# RAM intensive C# process getting slower after several hours

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, memory-management, html-agility-pack

I run a C# process (service) on a server responsible for parsing HTML pages continuously. It relies on HTMLAgilityPack. The symptom is that it becomes slower and slower as time goes by.

When I start the process, it handles n pages/s. After a a few hours, the speed goes down to around n/2 pages/s. It can go down to n/10 after a few days. The phenomenon has been observed many times and is rather deterministic. Anytime the process is restarted things are back to normal.

Very importantly: I can run other calculations in the same process and they are not slowed down: I can reach 100% CPU with anything I want at any time. The process itself is not slow. Only HTML parsing slows down.

I could reproduce it with minimal code (actually the behaviour in the original service is a bit more extreme but still this piece of code reproduces the behaviour):

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
    string url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Texas_A%26M_University";
    string html = new HtmlWeb().Load(url).DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
    while (true) {
        //Processing
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        Parallel.For(0, 10000, i => new HtmlDocument().LoadHtml(html));
        sw.Stop();
        //Logging
        using(var writer = File.AppendText("c:\\parsing.log")) {
            string text = DateTime.Now.ToString() + ";" + (int) sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
            writer.WriteLine(text);
            Console.WriteLine(text);
        }
    }
}
```

With this minimal code, this displays the speed (pages per second) as a function of the numbers of hours elapsed since the process was started:

[image]

Every obvious causes have been ruled out:

- the HTML pages are bigger or different (in the minimal code it's the same page)
- full RAM: the process uses around 500 MB on 32 GB
- other processes use CPU or RAM

It could be something about RAM and memory allocation. I know that HTMLAgilityPack makes a lot of small object memory allocation (HTML nodes and strings). It is clear memory allocation and multi-threading do not work well together. But I don't understand how the process can become slower and slower.

**Do you know of anything about the CLR or Windows that could be causing some RAM intensive (many allocations) processing to become slower and slower?** Like for example penalizing threads doing memory allocations in a certain way?

Comment: Hard to say without some code to reason with but if you do not find the reason you should move processing to a separate process. For each file (or batch) the service merely executes a separate process for that.

Comment: Yes it will be solution if I don't find the cause...

Comment: You need to post code, otherwise this is too broad and we'll not be able to help you

Comment: Can you show some code? To answer your question: tons. That's way we need to see the code.

Comment: Can you describe the "Process (Service)" ? is it web based? In other words we know it creates html but is it hosted on the web i.e. web service?

Comment: HTML uses TCP as transport layer.  Sometimes the table that are used with TCP start growing larger slowing down the system.  You may want to use a sniffer on the TCP and see if there are any retires and the time to ACK each datagram.  It may provide a clue to root causes.

Comment: @jdweng "HTML uses TCP as transport layer.", did you mean HTTP? HTML does not use anything as transport because it's a language

Comment: What do you really mean by _process_? You seem to be describing something _ongoing_ ("after one day"), versus, say, a scheduled task.

Comment: This is precisely where a [mcve] would be awesome. As a matter of fact, without one this is off-topic for the site.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: Did you dispose filestream explicitly after using it？Is it possible that Windows hold many file handles waiting for GC？

Comment: It's not possible to answer this without a lot more detail. Attach a profiler to your process and monitor it over time for memory / CPU use, threads, etc.

Comment: I provided the minimal code and @ComputerTrading provided the answer I was looking for. Maybe you can remove the "on hold" status.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have noticed similar behaviour using the HTMLAgilityPack.

I have found that when one yield's data it starts to space leak local variables on the compiler generated classes that start to cause problems. As no code is available, here's my First Aid kit.

1. Make sure you set [the right strategy](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/07/20/the-net-framework-4-5-includes-new-garbage-collector-enhancements-for-client-and-server-apps/), changing the GC collection strategy in the app.config will help the fragmentation.
2. Make sure you null things when you do not need them, as soon as you do not need them, do not wait for the scope to clean your memory as the IEnumerables get called in the calling method and scope of method variables and can live far longer than you think! Open your code in ILSpy and look at the *<>d__0(0)* generated classes. You will see things generated like d__.X=X; in this case X could hold a fragment or a whole page.
3. Your local variables are hoisted to the heap as they can't be accessed in the IEnumable iterations if they would not be there.
4. Locking starts becoming an issue, large items are bleading in your 4th generation ram that are actually going to start blocking the GC. The GC is pausing your threads in able to perform garbage collection.
5. The worst thing of HTMLAgility is that it [fragments that ends up being a real issue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973837.aspx)

   I am quite sure that when you start to consider the scope of your HTML fragments you will find that things will start going well. Have a look at your execution using [WinDbg in SOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugging-managed-code) and make a dump of your memory and have a look.

How to do that.

1. open WinDebug, press F6 and attach to the process (enter the process ID in the field and press ok)
2. then load the execution in your memory by entering

   ```
   .loadby sos clr
   ```
3. then enter

   ```
   !dumpheap -stat
   ```

You'd then get the memory items allocated in your application with the memory address and the size grouped by type and sorted from low header to high header you will see something like System.String[] with a massive number in front of it, that's the stuff you would like to investigate first.

Now to see who has that you can type

```
!dumpheap -mt <heap address>
```

And you will see the addresses that are using that memory table (MT) and the size of ram it uses.

Now it becomes interesting, rather than you going through x100 lines of code you type

```
!gcroot <address>
```

what it will print is the file and line of code that allocated the memory, the compiler generated class and the variable causing you grief as well as the bytes it holds.

This is what one could call "production debugging" and works if you have access to the server, which I guess you have.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this step by step.

Comment: Hi Bernoid, WinDbg is definitely a magic tool worth looking into, there are some nice videos on how to use it in https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=WinDbg

Comment: I was using the wrong GC. I switched to server and disabled concurrency. Parsing is 10x faster from the start and stays fast. Maybe you can insist on it in your answer: make it clear that server GC must be used. Even though I had already read things about it it was unclear in my head. You saved my life (at least) :-) I'll look at WinDbg soon.

Comment: Glad to have been of help

Comment: I wonder how many other users are going to pick up on the fact that a change in the app.config can make their application "10x faster". GC is so often overlooked, I find that most do not even know it has settings

Comment: Few. Before I asked things were unclear in my head. I confused gcConcurrent and gcServer tags. I've asked questions about it for a week trying to fix the problem including on HAP and AngleSharp projects. The fact is unless you're lucky and allocate memory by big blocks, intensive multithreading simply does not work with default GC configuration. Symptoms vary quite a bit. See https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp/issues/670. Maybe Microsoft should write it in red somewhere.

Comment: If you have access to the source code and you can make changes open a defect and have them explicitly empty, then null the local variables that are generated using the parser. Nulling will just remove the pointer and allow the html file to stay in memory, empty it will "overwrite" it